# Cardinality of the set $A$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $A=\{(m,n,p)\in \mathbb{N}^3: \frac{1}{n}+ \frac{1}{m}+ \frac{1}{p}=1\}$ then find cardinality of $A$.

I have tried this and I get $(3,3,3)$,$(2,4,4)$, and $(2,3,6)$. But if $m\neq n \neq p$ then I can't conclude: is there  any other solution except $(2,3,6)$?

Please help

Answer (score 2):

You have all of them (modulo permutations). Here is a proof:

For now let us ignore permutations and so assume that $n\geq m\geq p$. Note that $p>1$.

Case 1: $p=2$. Since $n\neq 0$, $m > 2$. for $m=3\Rightarrow n=6.$ Also $m=4\Rightarrow n=4$. If $m\geq5$ then since $n\geq m$ we have $\frac{1}{n}\leq\frac{1}{5}$ and thus

$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{p}\leq \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{9}{10}.$$

Thus $m\leq 4$.

Case 2: $p=3$. You can follow similar logic to see that $p=m=n=3$ is the only possibility.

Case 3: $p>3$ then $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{p} \leq \frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}<1$.

Thus the options are $\{(2,3,6),(2,4,4),(3,3,3)\}$. Now get all permutations of those and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take, although I did not actually calculate the number of solutions, I can prove there are finitely many.

The proof is as follows:
suppose $n,m,k\in \Bbb N$ are solutions of:
$$\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{k}=1$$
then:
$$k=\frac{nm}{nm-n-m}$$
for large enough $n,m$ we have:
$$1<\frac{nm}{nm-n-m}<2$$
and so $k\notin\Bbb{N}$
which is a contradiction so there are finnitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.  If they are not all equal, one has to be $2$ or the sum will be too small.  Then you need a second to be $3$ or again it will be too small.  You have to count the number of ways to put each solution in order and add them up.